# CSS @keyframes translate animation blink after display none

Tags: javascript, css

I want to take place of fading place with smooth animation using      @keyframes transform translate    in it then    display:none
Unfortunately it seems like    display:none    dragging animated content back for a moment so it's blinking :(
**Some**times it's not if change @keyframes delay to few milliseconds less
There is some way to fit these animations?
//Maybe without css at all?

```js
var delayForHeader = setInterval(fade, 1000); 
var s = document.getElementById('containerHeader').style;  
var bodyMove = document.getElementById('change');
function fade(){
 s.transition="opacity 1s"; s.opacity=0;   
 setTimeout(function(){bodyMove.className="moveUp animated";},1000); 
 setTimeout(function(){s.display="none";},2000);      
 }
```

```css
 .moveUp { 
            animation-name: def;
         }
  .animated {  
            animation-duration: 1s; 
            animation-fill-mode: forward;
         }
@keyframes def {
            0% { 
               transform: translateY(0px);
            }
            100% { 
               transform: translateY(-243px);
            }
         }
```

```html
<div id="containerHeader" onload="delayForHeader"> <p style="background-color: green; display:block; padding: 100px;"> stackowerflow <3 </p> </div>
<div id="change" style="background-color: black; display: block; padding: 20px; color: white;">blink</div>
```

Comment: It's `forwards`, not `forward`.

Comment: My apologies, there is should be "none" . Anyway  it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

fixed with

```js
setTimeout(fade, 1000);

var cnt = document.getElementById('containerHeader');
cnt.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
  bodyMove.className="moveUp animated";
})

var bodyMove = document.getElementById('change');
bodyMove.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
  s.display = "none";
});

var s = cnt.style;  
function fade(){ 
 s.transition="opacity 1s";
  s.opacity=0;
}
```

```css
.moveUp { 
            animation-name: def;
         }
  .animated {  
            animation-duration: 1s; 
            animation-fill-mode: forward;
         }
@keyframes def {
            0% { 
               transform: translateY(0px);
            }
            100% { 
               transform: translateY(-243px);
            }
         }
```

```html
<div id="containerHeader"> <p style="background-color: green; display:block; padding: 100px;">  суп  </p> </div>
<div id="change" style="background-color: black; display: block; padding: 20px; color: white;">not blinking</div>
```